# Scrapy install: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Tags: python, macos, gcc, scrapy

I am trying to install [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) on a a Mac OS X 10.6.2 machine... 
When I try to build one of the dependent modules ( libxml2 )

I am getting the following error:

```
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

I assume I need the gcc compiler ... is that easy to install on 10.6? Is there some sort of package I should be installing, so as  to not get hunged up like this installing modules in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the Apple Xcode Development tools. There would be on [Apple Developer Connection site](http://connect.apple.com/) or on your Mac OS X installation CDs/DVD. Ensure that the optional components for command line development are installed ("Unix Development" in the Xcode 3.x installer)

Answer (score 2):

Might be of interest to know that upgrading from OS X 10.5 to 10.6 [apparently](http://www.brianp.net/2009/09/05/snow-leopards-ate-my-c-compiler/) unlinks the existing developer tools thus requiring a reinstall from the SL DVD for gcc to work as usual.

Most annoying when you thought you had everything set up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install XCode ('developer tools') from the Snow Leopard DVD - this includes gcc among much other stuff. You should also run software update after the install to freshen it